# containsMatchingElement returns false when react component contains function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a child component which contains a method as props. This child component renders Radio Group. When I click these radio buttons based on the value of radio another component gets rendered. I have two issues.

1. I'm not able to invoke child component props method (setSeverityLevel)
2. containsMatchingElement() returns false even though debug shows the component available.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { SelectSeverityLevel } from "components/Common/SelectSeverityLevel";
import Sev1Confirmation from "../Sev1Confirmation";

interface State {
  issueSummary: string;
  description: string;
  createIncidentRequested: boolean;
  selectedSeverity: TicketSeverityEnum;
  errorMessage: JSX.Element;
}

export class TechnicalSRCreate extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      issueSummary: undefined,
      description: undefined,
      createIncidentRequested: false,
      selectedSeverity: "HIGH",
      errorMessage: undefined
    };
  }
  private sev1Confirmation = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <Sev1Confirmation 
        checked={this.props.sev1Confirmed}
        confirm={(value: boolean) => {
          this.props.setSev1Confirmed(value);
        }}
      />);
  }
  private onSelectSeverity = (value: string): void => {
    console.log("onSelectSeverity>>>");
    console.log(value);
    this.props.setSeverity(value as TicketSeverityEnum);
  }

  private internalRender(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
        <SelectSeverityLevel
          defaultSeverity={this.props.severity}
          fieldName={SeverityLevelFieldName}
          setSeverityLevel={this.onSelectSeverity}
        />
        {this.props.severity === "HIGHEST" ? 
          this.sev1Confirmation()
        : null}
        </>
    )
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
        <Form>
            .....
            <div>{this.internalRender()}</div>
        </Form>
        </>

    )
  }
}
export default TechnicalSRCreate;
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The shallow render is not meant for this purposes, quoting from the [docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html):

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components.

You should use `mount(...)` instead to test child-parent behavior. Also, a good rule of thumb is to always test components using `mount` instead of `shallow` as the latter allows you to break your application without the tests failing; and maintaining the App must be the longterm ambition. Read more about this [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering)

Comment: I tried with mount as well and still tests fails.
 
const parent = mount(<TechnicalSRCreate refresh={jest.fn()} setSubmitEnable={Boolean} setSev1Confirmed={Boolean} setSeverity={jest.fn()} severity={"HIGH"} sev1Confirmed={true}/>);
expect(parent.containsMatchingElement(<SelectSeverityLevel fieldName="foo" setSeverityLevel={onSetSeverityLevel}/>)).toBe(true);

 Expected: true
 Received: false

Comment: Without a reproducible example, there's really not a lot I can tell from that.

Comment: Updated the question with reproducible example